# Powershell Remove Printer

Tags: powershell

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Printer | where{$_.Network -eq ‘true‘}| foreach{$_.delete()}
```

I know this script will delete all network printers, but I need to delete only certain network printers…like CLEPRINT15-2 and CLEPRINT 15-4, but not 15-3. How would I do this?

Comment: Is there a 'name' property (or similar)?

Comment: The name would be CLEPRINT-15-2

Answer (score 2):

You already have a where filter on the Network property just more conditionals on the Name property.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Printer |
    Where-Object {$_.Network -eq $true -and ($_.Name -eq 'CLEPRINT15-2' -or $_.Name -eq 'CLEPRINT15-4')} |
    ForEach-Object {$_.Delete()}
```

Note: Also be careful with smart quotes. `‘` is different than `'`

Answer (score 1):

Try this additional where condition with a RegEx class [24]:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Printer | 
    where{$_.Network -eq $true -and $_.Name -match '^CLEPRINT-?15-[24]$'} | 
        foreach{$_.delete()}
```

Comment: `Network` is a boolean `NoteProperty` on the `ManagementObject`, so it'd be better to compare to `$true` or just do `$_.Network` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, changed @TheIncorrigible1